# How to check whether key or value exist in Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have a scala Map and would like to test if a certain value exists in the map.

```
myMap.exists( /*What should go here*/ )
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

There are several different options, depending on what you mean.

If you mean by "value" *key-value pair*, then you can use something like

```
myMap.exists(_ == ("fish",3))
myMap.exists(_ == "fish" -> 3)
```

If you mean *value of the key-value pair*, then you can

```
myMap.values.exists(_ == 3)
myMap.exists(_._2 == 3)
```

If you wanted to just test *the key of the key-value pair*, then

```
myMap.keySet.exists(_ == "fish")
myMap.exists(_._1 == "fish")
myMap.contains("fish")
```

Note that although the tuple forms (e.g. `_._1 == "fish"`) end up being shorter, the slightly longer forms are more explicit about what you want to have happen.

Comment: Also worth saying that for testing existence of a key, the library provides myMap.contains("fish")

Comment: @DaveGriffith - Indeed.  I was just using "exists", but that one's important enough (since it is the one you _should_ use) to add in.  I've amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 32):

Do you want to know if the *value* exists on the map, or the key? If you want to check the key, use `isDefinedAt`:

```
myMap isDefinedAt key
```

Answer (score 10):

you provide a test that one of the map values will pass, i.e.

```
val mymap = Map(9->"lolo", 7->"lala")
mymap.exists(_._1 == 7) //true
mymap.exists(x => x._1 == 7 && x._2 == "lolo") //false
mymap.exists(x => x._1 == 7 && x._2 == "lala") //true
```

The ScalaDocs say of the method "Tests whether a predicate holds for some of the elements of this immutable map.", the catch is that it receives a tuple (key, value) instead of two parameters.

Answer (score 8):

What about this:

```
val map = Map(1 -> 'a', 2 -> 'b', 4 -> 'd')
map.values.toSeq.contains('c')  //false
```

Yields `true` if map contains `c` value.

If you insist on using `exists`:

```
map.exists({case(_, value) => value == 'c'})
```

Comment: `values` creates a new `Iterable` so you probably are better off with `map.valuesIterator.contains('c')` (although that's not as easy as `map.exists(_._2 == 'c')`!)

Answer (score 6):

Per answers above, note that exists() is significantly slower than contains() (I've benchmarked with a Map containing 5000 string keys, and the ratio was a consistent x100). I'm relatively new to scala but my guess is exists() is iterating over all keys (or key,value tupple) whereas contains uses Map's random access