# Return in a map

Tags: scala

Is it possible to directly return a response inside a map otherwise than doing that:

```
var authorized = false
roles.map { role => 
    val method = userRole.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(role.toString)
    authorized = method.invoke(userRole).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
}
authorized
```

or is it the only way? I've learned that it's better to avoid using var.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether key or value exist in Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567744/how-to-check-whether-key-or-value-exist-in-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check if there exists an element in your list that satisfies some condition, you can use the `exists` method:

```
list.exists(value => condition(value))
```

**Edit after the question was changed**:

You can still use `exists` for this case, but if you want to invoke all the methods, you need to use `map` first (assuming your list is eager):

```
roles.map { role => 
    userRole.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(role.toString).invoke(userRole)
}.exists(_.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
```

If you don't need to call all methods (which you probably don't need to if the methods are pure), you can just use `exists`:

```
roles.exists { role =>
    userRole.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(role.toString)
            .invoke(userRole).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
}
```

Comment: It's unfortunately not an existence check, it's more complex than that

Comment: Perhaps if you can elaborate in your question the answer can be more accurate, otherwise this answer fits the specified problem pretty well.

Comment: Do you think you can do everything in one pass within the `exists` call? Otherwise you would have to traverse the collection twice (unless it's a `Stream` or you make it one).

Comment: The `exists` call short-circuits when it hits a match, so unless he wants to invoke all methods, he can just use `exists`.